# Issue with symbol "&" in REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

In REST API when I pass a value with `&`(ex: `India & China`), it throws error and when I checked it in browser it shows `&amnp;` in place of `&`.

```
https://test/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Team')/Items?$filter=(Title eq 'India & China')
```

What shall I do to fix this?

Comment: You are missing to close the value in the end. (').

Comment: Try use `encodeURI()` on your value (see http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164673/sharepoint-rest-api-getbytitle-with-ampersand-in-title)

Comment: Any help from my answer? @vikashkumar

Comment: yes, but it was not working by directly putting it to the url so I have taken a variable to store encodeURIComponent("India & China")+"') and then I added it to url.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `encodeURIComponent()` not `encodeURI()`

Query Url should look like

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Team')/Items?$filter=(Title eq '"+encodeURIComponent("India & China")+"')
```

## `encodeURIComponent()` vs `encodeURI()`

If list name contains any special character like  /, ?, :, @, &, =, +, $ or #, then use `encodeURI()`.

In `$filter` always use `encodeURIComponent()`.