# Problem when querying my security group using REST API when the group name contain "&"

Tags: 2013, javascript, development, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I am facing this problem which i can not find a solution for inside my sharepoint farm 2013 on-premises. now i have a security group named "`Users & Workers`" and inside my javascript i am querying this security group, as follow:-

```
/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('User & Workers')/users/
```

but i am getting this error:-

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&amp;).
```

i think the problem is related to the face that the group name contain this charecter `&`. so is there a way to fix this ?

here is my javascript code which is responsible to do the call:-

```
url = "/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname(" + "'" + FieldValue + "')/users/";
$.ajax({
     url: url,
     method: "GET",
     async: false,
     headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
     success: function (data) {
```

where the `FieldValue` will be equal to `User & Workers`

here is the code from firefox F12 tools:-

```
GET http://t*******/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('Users%20&%20Workers')/users/

400 Bad Request
        110ms   
jquery-1.10.2.js (line 8720)
"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request -
```

Comment: I have same problem with asterisk(*) - replacing it with %2a doesn't help

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with `&` SharePoint on premises some rest api call. I have tested your scenario and I could achieve with different query

```
var groupName = encodeURIComponent(groupName);
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups?$filter=Title eq '" + groupName + "'"
```

or

```
var groupName = encodeURIComponent(groupName);
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups?$filter=LoginName eq '" + groupName + "'"
```

My example is as follows

```
//my groups is "Owners & Members"
http://sp-2013ent:1111/_api/web/sitegroups?$filter=LoginName eq 'Owners%20%26%20Members'
```

This is 100% working on 2013/2016 on-premises servers

Get Id from above call and use for your next calls to get users. Example as below

```
http://sp-2013ent:1111/_api/web/sitegroups/GetById(8)/Users
```

I know this requires additional call but solves your problem

Comment: thanks for your answer, will try this .. but i can not understand why you are doing `substringof` inside the filter ? one time you used LoginName the other you used Title ..

Comment: second question also when i do the following call `"/_api/web/sitegroups` inside my RESTClient tool, the security group will have the following values `<d:LoginName>Users &amp; Workers</d:LoginName>
<d:Title>Users &amp; Workers</d:Title>` so i am not sure why the Title and LoginName will have `amp;` inside them...

Comment: I got failed when I put `Title eq 'Owners %26 Members'` but you can try that first it works you can use that. The LoginName and Title work same I have give LoginName just to match your call `getByName` rest call. The `&` is an XML compliant character so it will always be converted to `&amp;`

Comment: now you approach works for almost all the group names.. but i have noted that it will fail if i have 2 groups containing the same sting so let say i have a group named "users & workers" and another group named "user & workers 2" .. then doing a substring on "users & workers" will return the 2 groups !! unlike when i search by title i will always get atmost one results or no results...so is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I have tested query again with `eq` filter surprisingly it is working. I might have typo in query yesterday. So now you replace filter condition as `$filter=Title eq 'Owners %26 Members'`. It solves your problem. I am changing my answer also.

Comment: now using the `eq` instead of `substringof` allow the script to work in-case i have 2 security groups , and one of the security groups contain the other security group name as part of his name such as "Reader" & "Advance Reader".. where using `substringof` i will get an error since i will be mainly getting 2 results.. while using the eq i will get only one result based on the search criteria.. but still using `eq` will do a case sensitive search,, so is there a way to force the `eq` to do case insensitive search ?

Comment: Strangely the filter operation `eq` works case insensitive but when it comes to `sitegroups` it is working on case-sensitive. This might be an issue with REST API. In this case, you can force a user to type exact match string or need to find a way to give a dropdown with a list of groups prepopulated.

Comment: so i can not force the `eq` to do a case insensitive search ???

Comment: Yes with site groups

Comment: what do you mean by `Yes with site groups`??now in my case the `eq` will do a case sensitive match on the group names.. which does not make sense since the group names are case insensitive,, as i can not have 2 groups one named as "Test" while the other as "test"..

Comment: I agree with your comment. As of now, I can`t think of an alternate way other than providing exact group name in the query or giving a dropdown option with pre-filled group names. This might be a bug in API.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to run the title through a url encoder so the REST API engine doesn't have a fit. Try this:

```
url = "/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname(" + "'" + encodeURI(FieldValue) + "')/users/";
```

or you can do it to the entire URI.

Comment: but still i got the same exception ,, and inside my firefox F12 the url will be as follow `Users%20&%20Workers`.. so why the & is not being encoded ?

Comment: try `encodeURIComponent(FieldValue)`

Comment: now using `encodeURIComponent(FieldValue)` the value will be as follow `Users%20%26%20Workers` so the & got encoded as %26 which is compatible with what is mentioned here http://prasannaadavi.com/2014/06/handling-special-characters-in-odata-queries.html#.WTC7Ody1upq but still i will be getting the same error.... looks to me like a bug in sharepoint rest api.. what do u think ?

Comment: I think there is no bug in the request. I am able to get my group and users which has been tested on SharePoint online site. `https://xyz.sharepoint.com/_api/web/sitegroups/getByName('Owners%20%26%20Members')/users`

Comment: @VenkatKonjeti i am using sharepoint 2013 on-premise . and seems as mentoned on this link also https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164673/sharepoint-rest-api-getbytitle-with-ampersand-in-title that users can not get this working on on-premises!! while on SP online seems it is working well..

Comment: I can't get it working on SharePoint Online, but in my case the problem is asterisk(*) - replacing it with %2a doesn't help.