# SharePoint REST API getbytitle with a slash in title?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

How to reproduce the problem:

- Have a list with a title: `Mapped Drives / Folder Redirection`
- Open this list using this URL `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Mapped Drives / Folder Redirection')`
- Or open it using this url: `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Mapped%20Drives%20%2F%20Folder%20Redirection')`

The result is:
[image]

I've found a similar question, but it does not have a solution. At least none that would solve the problem of having a slash in the title
[SharePoint REST API getbytitle with ampersand in title?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164673/sharepoint-rest-api-getbytitle-with-ampersand-in-title)

Is there are way to query a list by title via REST if it contains a slash symbol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The REST API `Lists/getByTitle('')` does not support the special character `/`. You have to get it by using one of the following ways.

**Using GUID**

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web/Lists(guid'your guid')
```

**Using Filter Operation**

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web/Lists?$filter=Title eq 'your list title'
```

If you want to get the items from the list using the title. You have to make 2 calls.

1. Get List Guid from below query. Example

   `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web/Lists?$filter=Title eq 'test/List'&$select=Id`
2. Use the Id from the above response to get the items

   `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web/Lists(guid'guid from above request')/Items`

Answer (score 0):

Although you came up with a workaround, I'm curious whether either of these suggestions would have worked for you:

- Use the URL encoded version of the call

  - `Mapped Drives / Folder Redirection` would be `Mapped%20Drives%20%2F%20Folder%20Redirection`
  - It should be valid OData call as per [this](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398071)
- Wrap the title with `encodeURIComponent()`:

  - `/getByTitle('" + encodeURIComponent('Mapped Drives / Folder Redirection') + "')`

I have come up with findings of both of the mentioned where they have worked in a similar case.

Comment: Hi Moe, thank you for the answer. As you can see, encodeURIComponent('Mapped Drives / Folder Redirection')  produces Mapped%20Drives%20%2F%20Folder%20Redirection. And this is exactly what I used in the question and specified that it throws an error. as Venkat Konjeti said, you cannot get run Lists/getByTitle('') if the list contains a slash symbol. No matter if you try to escape it with encodeURIComponent or not.

Comment: Cheers @DenisMolodtsov, kinda what I was expecting. Why I still suggested this was because I have come across cases where `getByTitle` is successfully used with special characters, which made me question the unambiguous explanation here.

Comment: I really like the $filter=Title eq 'your list title' solution since it produces nearly identical response as Lists/getByTitle(''). And I don't need to make 2 calls instead of one.